# Not able to connect to Google Tag Manager API via C# API using Service Account

Tags: c#, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-authentication, gtm-oauth2

I'm trying to access Google Tag Manager API to get the list of my Tags via my C# Web API
As mentioned in the documentation, authorization is only possible via OAuh 2.0 hence I have created a service account so that my web API can interact with google cloud services without any user interaction.
I have downloaded the JSON/P12 Key and stored it in my solution and was able to extract the key
But when I pass that key to Google Tag Manager API in the Header in HTTPClient Request I'm getting an error as not found

Following is the code snippet I'm using

```
        string token = "";
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(jsonKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            token = await GoogleCredential
                .FromStream(stream)
                .CreateScoped(new []{ TagManagerService.Scope.TagmanagerReadonly})
                .UnderlyingCredential
                .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
        }
        using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://tagmanager.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/{accountid}/containers/{containerid}/workspaces/{workspaceid}/tags";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // this is always returning false
        {
            log(response);
        }
```

I tried finding some resources online but no help there is very little documentation related to .Net framework support
Also, the token extracted via `GoogleCredential` contains a lot of dots at the end
something like this

```
ta27.c.dzj7GOL8nadWmrqM74......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

In response I'm getting, status as NotFound

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution to the problem was with container access
I had to add my service account email as a user to my google tag manager container
And it worked